# nginx keeps download the index.php not executing

Tags: nginx, php-7

I'm setting up a server with nginx and php7

Here my config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/home;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;
    charset   utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php\$ {
        try_files \$uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)\$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But this keeps downloading the index.php, also when I enter the IP it redirects to the index.php - IP/index.php

UPDATE:
change the location `location ~ \.php\$ {` to `location ~ \.php$ {` stop downloading the file.
However now I got the error:

```
29861#29861: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: \/var/www/home\/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: ..., server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "..."
```

Comment: in my configuration there is not \ before the $uri. any way - the problem could be in the fastcgi configuration.

Comment: not it's the same

Comment: what about your fastcgi/fpm configuration?

Comment: check my update, may be the problem

Comment: Remove the `\$uri` and put `$uri` instead. the same with `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME`: remove the `\\`

Comment: that's correct, thank you